# Finding and printing a string that has white space using for loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, whitespace

I am trying to print any email addresses that are invalid.  To be invalid, the email addresses need to not contain an @ sign, a period, or a space.  The code I have is returning email addresses that do not have an @ sign or a period, but they are not returning email addresses that have a space in them.

```
public static void print_emails(){
    for (int i = 0; i < student.size(); i++) {


        if (student.get(i).getEmail().contains("@") && student.get(i).getEmail().contains(".") && student.get(i).getEmail().contains("")){
            System.out.println("Scanning Roster");
        }

        else if (student.get(i).getEmail().contains("\\s")){
            System.out.println("Invalid email address, " + student.get(i).getEmail());
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid email address, " + student.get(i).getEmail());

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing it would be to match the email string against a regular expression. The following should work:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@(.+)$
```

This is a very simple one, which you could make increasingly complex to suit your needs. Currently, this one ensures:

1) A-Z and a-z characters are allowed

2) 0-9 numbers are allowed

3) The email may contain only dot(.), dash(-) and underscore(_)

As well as allowing the @ symbol in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

`contains()` is expecting a `CharSequence`. Use regex instead:

```
else if (studentList.get(i).getEmail().matches(".*\\s.*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to include this:

```
public static void print_invalid_emails()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (studentList.get(i).getEmail().contains("@") && studentList.get(i).getEmail().contains(".") && !studentList.get(i).getEmail().contains(" "))
        {
            System.out.println("Scanning Roster");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid email address, " + studentList.get(i).getEmail());
        }
    }
}
```